# Customised semantic-ui-react Menu

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using `semantic-ui-react` for sometime now, everything works fine for me but I have an issue with my Navigation Menu.

The thing is that I want it to be customised for mobile and desktop, so in other words I want a complete different implementation for mobile and desktop and I was wondering if there is a proper way to do that using customised semantic (as I am already customising the theme etc etc).

Another thought I have is that maybe there is the `only` option available for Menu but havent really found anything in documentation.

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the `Grid` component has viewport breakpoints (in vanilla SUI, too), so you should wrap your menus into it.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Row columns={1} only='mobile'>
    <Grid.Column>
      <MobileMenu />
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
  <Grid.Row columns={1} only='tablet computer'>
    <Grid.Column>
      <ComputerMenu />
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

You can also check [device visibility](http://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#grid-example-only) section of `Grid`'s docs.